# Using length function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm begining my learning of OCaml and I have been quite stuck on a simple problem.
I'm trying to count with a simple loop the number of letters that I have in a file of 6 lines.
Here's my code :

```
let fi = open_in "example";;
let string = "";;
let nb_carac = 0;;

for i = 0 to 6 do
  string = input_line fi; 
  nb_carac = (nb_carac + String.length(string));
  done;;
```

Problem is, it doesn't seem to count anything and reaches directly to `EOF`.
I get the following error message:

```
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
Exception: End_of_file.
```

I don't really get it. I have tried each line individually and they all worked. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If the post below answers your question please accept it by [clicking on the check sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) next to the answer. If it still doesn't answer your question, add more details to your question so that somebody can answer it. When you mark an answer as accepted, it float to the top so that other readers can see the working answer soon and the writer of answer and you are awarded some reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

OCaml does not have *mutable* variables. You should use [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) or [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29). Read any basic OCaml textbook or tutorial.

Both lines:

```
string = input_line fi; 
nb_carac = (nb_carac + String.length(string));
```

are understood as useless equality tests (this explains the warning you are getting).

Perhaps you want:

```
(* shameful *)
let string = ref "";;
let nb_carac = ref 0;;
```

then e.g.

```
(* shameful *)
string := input_line fi;
nb_carac := !nb_carac + String.length(!string);
```

but you should get a very bad grade if you code so imperatively in a functional language like OCaml.

As a rule of thumb, avoid mutating data when coding in OCaml. Of course there are important exceptions to this rule.

The correct solution to your exercise is to use tail recursive functions which do not mutate any data. Look at OCaml standard library [stdlib/list.ml](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/trunk/stdlib/list.ml?view=markup) for some inspiration.

Probably a better solution to your exercise starts with

```
let count_lines_and_characters fil = (* incomplete code, fill the ... *)
  let rec ....
  in ....
;;
```

Of course *you* should fill the ....

Comment: Thank you, it worked !
It was indeed pretty basic. I should be more careful and get used to it.
Thank you again.

Comment: BTW, what did work? Using references like I did above is a *shame* and you'll get a bad grade. You need to write some local tail recursive functions (and I did not do that for you, because *you* need to *think*).

Comment: Well, the purpose was to find a way to count every letter in a file with what my lessons taught me until now...
Just an exercice to get used to the language, little by little.